# Customization of legends in dimple.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dimple.js

I have a bar chart and i need to show six legends or more legends for the bar graph in a 3 X 3(3 legends per row) fashion.
How to do that. I am able to get only 2 legends per row. 
How to customize the number of legends in a row and if the text of the legend is bigger then it should be wrapped in a particular width.
Please let me know how to do that.

```
 var yMax = 520; // overriding y axis
var popup;
        var score=8000/100;
        var svg = dimple.newSvg("#chartContainer", 300, 400);
        var data = [{
            "Brand":"Aaaaa aaaaaaaaaaaaa", 
            "Day":"Mon", 
            "SalesVolume":100 },
            { 
            "Brand":"Bbbbbbbb bbbbbbbb", 
            "Day":"Mon", 
            "SalesVolume":200 },
            { 
            "Brand":"Cccccccccccccccc c", 
            "Day":"Mon", 
            "SalesVolume":200 },
            { 
            "Brand":"Ddddddddddd ddddddd", 
            "Day":"Mon", 
            "SalesVolume":200 },
            { 
            "Brand":"Eeeeeeeeeee eeeee", 
            "Day":"Mon", 
            "SalesVolume":200 },
            {  
            "Brand":"Fffffffffffff ffffffffffff", 
            "Day":"Mon", 
            "SalesVolume":200 }];
        var myChart = new dimple.chart(svg, data);

        myChart.setBounds(100, 10, 250, 250)
        var x = myChart.addCategoryAxis("x", "Day");
        var y = myChart.addMeasureAxis("y", "SalesVolume");
        y.overrideMax = yMax;
         y.addOrderRule("SalesVolume");
        var s = myChart.addSeries("Brand", dimple.plot.bar);
        s.barGap=0.8;
        var lgnd = myChart.addLegend(80, 300, 300, 30, "left");
lgnd.horizontalPadding = 1000;
lgnd.verticalPadding = 10000;

myChart.draw();     
        //d3.selectAll("rect").on("mouseover", null);

function wrap(text, width) {
  text.each(function() {
    var text = d3.select(this),
        words = text.text().split(/\s+/).reverse(),
        word,
        line = [],
        lineNumber = 0,
        lineHeight = 1.1, // ems
        x = text.attr("x"),
        y = text.attr("y"),
        dy = parseFloat(text.attr("dy")),
        tspan = text.text(null).append("tspan").attr("x", x).attr("y", y-10).attr("dy", 1 + "em");
        console.log(y);
    while (word = words.pop()) {
      line.push(word);
      tspan.text(line.join(" "));
      if (tspan.node().getComputedTextLength() > width) {
        line.pop();
        tspan.text(line.join(" "));
        line = [word];
        tspan = text.append("tspan").attr("x", x).attr("y", y+10).attr("dy", 1 + "em").text(word);
      }
    }
  });
}

d3.selectAll(".legendText")
  .call(wrap, 100);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/keshav_1007/qec4L4zh/1/ - here is my fiddle

I changed the code using d3.js and i am able to wrpa the text now but i am unable to change the position of the legends(rect). Because if the legend text is wrapped then the next legend should come after the wrapped text. but now it is overlapping. Please let me know how to solve this..

Comment: anyone know about this??

Comment: Can't you just look at the rendered DOM and figure out how to access the various components?

Comment: @cool I tried but couldnt make it work.. and thats why i posted this question here :)